# Why will my other child div not move on hover?

Tags: css, hover

So I have this situation :

```
<div class="relations-container">
    <div class="relations">
    <ul>
      <? while($relatedVideo = mysql_fetch_array($relatedVideos)){ ?>
    <li><p><a href="?prodId=<?=$relatedVideo['recProductId']?>"><?
            =$relatedVideo['recTitle']?></a></p></li>
      <? } ?>
    </ul>
    </div>
         <? } ?>
     <div class="relations-button">
     </div>
</div>
```

So I have my container div "relations-container", which contains my 2 child divs "relations" and "relations-button"

my css is as follows :

```
.relations-container{
height:82px;
width:auto;
position:relative;
bottom:456px;
float:left;
}

.relations {

width:720px;
height:50px;
background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
border:dotted #333 1px;
float:left;
position:relative;

}

.relations ul {
    list-style: none;
}
.relations ul li{
margin-left:10px;
width:20%;
float:left;
}

.relations ul li p {

font-family: verdana;
font-size:10px;
color:#666;
}

.relations-button{
height:30px;
width:30px;
background-color:rgb(0, 51, 153);
float:left;

}
```

What I am trying to achieve here is when I hover over the div "relations-button" this moves the div "relations" down by 50px. 
so I thought this would be :

```
.relations-button:hover + .relations{
position:relative;
top:50px
}
```

Does anyone know why the div isnt moving ?

Comment: This might help to start

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347905/animate-one-div-when-the-mouse-hovers-over-another

Comment: Your current structure is `.relations + .relations-button`. You cannot style a preceding element with CSS3.

Comment: this worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603497/div-class-hover-not-working-properly-in-ie

Comment: Thanks for the info Zeta , ive done something like this before and couldnt work out what was different this time but i wasnt using a preceding element. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use jQuery (JavaScript) for what you're trying to achieve.

```
$('.relations-button').hover(
function()
{
    $('.relations').css('top', '50');
},
function()
{
    $('.relations').css('top', '0');
});
```

Here's a live example to showcase how it works for a better understanding: http://jsfiddle.net/RxB9G/1/